# Algorithmic complexity of Sub-array with sum = target algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, search

Question:  Given an array of positive integers and a target total of X, find if there exists a contiguous subarray with sum = X

E.g:  If array is [1, 3, 5, 18] and X = 8 Output: True, if X = 10, output is FALSE.

Approach I can think of is to expand sub-array window, until you hit an index such that sum of sub-array == target or > target.  If > target, decrease sub-array by moving first element to the right.

It appears that in worst-case complexity is O(N) since I am moving either start or end index of sub-arrays, so int worst case I will just spend 2*N iterations. Is that correct analysis?

```
BOOL checkIfArrHasSum(long *arr, size_t size; long target)
{
  long currSum = [arr[0] longValue];
  long startInd = 0;
  long nextIndToCheck = 1;

  while (nextIndToCheck < size)
  {
    if(currSum == target) return YES;

    if (currSum + arr[nextIndToCheck] == target)
      return YES;
    else if(currSum + arr[nextIndToCheck] < target)
    {
      currSum = currSum + arr[nextIndToCheck];
      nextIndToCheck++;
    }
    else
    {
      currSum = currSum - arr[startInd];  
      startInd++;
    }
    if(startInd == nextIndToCheck)
    {
        nextIndToCheck = startInd+1;
        currSum = arr[nextIndToCheck];
    }
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: You may be interested in [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis).